# How to edit the sorting order of New Products displayed on Magento homepage

Tags: sorting, home, cms-block, new-products

I am showing new products on homepage with the code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Now the results are shown from the oldest to newest.

How can i configure the ascending / descending, so i can see the newest to oldest ?

Comment: Please look at the link for the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308231/changing-the-new-product-widget-sort-order-in-magento

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Magento.SE! This is quite easy to do and will require that you make a module to rewrite the functionality of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`.

Once you've done that, you need to just make an edit to the `_getProductCollection` method modifying the collection:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();    
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc');

    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Developing your own custom module seems intimidating at first, but it's much easier than it first appears.  For a great guide on how to get started with Phil's first step, check out http://icecreamlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/magebook.pdf